# Android: Change priority of other applications

Tags: android, priority-queue

My question is simple, Can I change priorities of other applications from my application ?

A possible attempt could be using

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
          System.out.println("Receiver name:" + info.activityInfo.name + ";     priority=" + info.priority);
        }
```

And change priority of any other application from here like

```
info.priority = 0;
```

would this change priority ?

I am asking to get a logical answer, not a trial and error scheme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only change priorities of other applications on a rooted device. On a non-rooted device this would violate the security built in.

Comment: ain't there any other solution rather than rooting the device ?

Comment: No, the security built in to android prevents you interfering with other apps on the device, so this would only be possible on a rooted device as you'd need root access to change the priority of another app.